# How can I protect this 48VDC device from overvoltage?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, protection

I'm powering [this isolated DC/DC converter](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Murata-Power-Solutions/MER1S4812SC/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsc0tfZmXiUnThPvESwrHCWPCF8wQJ%252b8F0%3d) from a power supply that is a nominal 48V, but could potentially reach a maximum voltage of 56V. The datasheet for the converter says that the absolute maximum is 54V. How can I protect this chip from the potential 2V's above it's maximum?

This regulator is being used to power an isolated MOSFET gate driver.

Comment: Would your system be likely to see >54V for a long period of time, or are we talking spikes/surges/pulses ?

Comment: Maybe several diodes in series, or a few volt zener.  You don't want the input to drop below Vmin when you have 48V as input.

Comment: Its crude, but I would probably try to drop the voltage with some series diodes like George suggested. Since the maximum rated output current @12V is 84mA it would be about 20mA max on the input side. That means that you don't have to worry much about the diodes power dissipation. What is the minimum voltage of the PSU? I find +8V from nominal (20%) pretty high.

Comment: This is for a robotics competition. I normally see voltages around 50-51V in practice, with our team's powersupply. However the competition rules state that the powersupply voltage could be as high as 56V, but is generally set to 50.8V +/- 0.3V

Answer (score 4):

This is a concept that would typically work, you'd have to run the sums to see if it will work in all possible scenarios.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnubkB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 (a [DN2540](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/DN2540%20B060313.pdf)) acts like a resistor of some tens of ohms under normal conditions, so it drops some hundreds of mV typically. If the input voltage rises to allow the 48V zener to conduct, the gate-source voltage decreases to -3.5V and Q1 is guaranteed to be fully off. If the tolerance on the 48V zener is 5% (50.4V max), then the output voltage should not exceed 53.9V (a bit close!).

R2 and the 12V TVS are just to protect the gate (+/-20V abs max) against any transients on the power supply.

Comment: Shouldn't R1 connect to the input side?

Comment: @Andyaka I don't think it matters much in this case- power dissipated in R1 vs. Q1 and a bit poorer regulation if connected to the input.. at least that the way it looks right now.

Comment: The way I see it is that input power is from the left and output is on the right. Without anything to push a modicum of current into the zener, it won't work. I'm thinking source follower circuit or maybe I'm being stoopid?

Comment: @Andyaka Perhaps I should have pointed out explicitly that it's a depletion-mode MOSFET?

Comment: Very sneaky LOL

Answer (score 3):

A simple BJT emitter follower circuit should work: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWCkvR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output from the emitter is 0.7V below the base and the base is tied to a biased 47 volt zener diode. If the incoming supply rises, the output stays about 47 volts.

Comment: On what basis did you estimate value of R1 ?

Comment: @AlBundy from the required bias current for the Zener diode. Check the datasheet of the one you select, and it will describe the recommended current to ensure break-down is consistent. Otherwise just do a few tens of milliamps, always being aware of the total power rating for the package used.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for the BJT transistor?

EDIT: Actually, since the component cost of this would nearly be the same cost as a self built switching regulator, I'll just be switching my design to the TL2575HV

Comment: @froggy Probably a BC547 is worth looking into (847 is SMD part) but with maybe 35mA flowing thru it to the load and maybe 10V across it (worst case) it might not suit the SMD package. 10V at 35mA is of course 350mW so try and pick one with good thermal characteristics and good gain at close-to-saturation point for when the supply dips down below 48 volts.